# How to show Line label with two digits after dote?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot, ios8.1

i use a core plot in my Xcode project and have a problem with plot values.

How can i show number on the CPTScatterPlot?
My plot shows me only one digit after dot (36.6).
For example show me 36.665 or 36.001?

I add a screen preview.

[image: How show 36.21]

**INIT**

```
-(void)initLinePlotTmp
{
    //Initialize and display Graph (x and y axis lines)
    self.graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.graphView.bounds];
    self.hostView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.graphView.bounds];
    self.hostView.hostedGraph = self.graph;
    [self.graphView addSubview:hostView];

    //apply styling to Graph
    [self.graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme]];

    //set graph backgound area transparent
    self.graph.backgroundColor = nil;
    self.graph.fill = nil;
    self.graph.plotAreaFrame.fill = nil;
    self.graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea.fill = nil;

    //This removes top and right lines of graph
    self.graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil;
    //This shows x and y axis labels from 0 to 1
    self.graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;

    // set padding for graph from Left and Bottom
    self.graph.paddingBottom = 10;
    self.graph.paddingLeft = 50;
    self.graph.paddingRight = 0;
    self.graph.paddingTop = 10;

    //Define x and y axis range
    // x-axis from 0 to 100
    // y-axis from 0 to 300
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)self.graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(plotXMinRange)
                                                    length:CPTDecimalFromInt(plotXMaxRange)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(plotYMinRange)
                                                    length:CPTDecimalFromInt(plotYMaxRange)];

    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)self.graph.axisSet;

    NSNumberFormatter *axisLabelFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
    [axisLabelFormatter setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:NO];
    [axisLabelFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];


    //Define x-axis properties
    //x-axis intermediate interval 2
    axisSet.xAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromInt(plotXInterval);
    axisSet.xAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 1;
    axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLength = 5;
    axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLength = 7;
    axisSet.xAxis.title = @"Time(Hours)";
    axisSet.xAxis.titleOffset = 25;
    axisSet.xAxis.labelFormatter = axisLabelFormatter;

    //Define y-axis properties
    //y-axis intermediate interval = 50;
    axisSet.yAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromInt(plotYInterval);
    axisSet.yAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 4;
    axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLength = 5;
    axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLength = 7;
    axisSet.yAxis.title = @"Temperature";
    axisSet.yAxis.titleOffset = 30;
    axisSet.yAxis.labelFormatter = axisLabelFormatter;


    //Define line plot and set line properties
    self.linePlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    self.linePlot.dataSource = self;
    [self.graph addPlot:self.linePlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];

    //set line plot style
    CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [self.linePlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    lineStyle.lineWidth = 2;
    lineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
    self.linePlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;

    CPTMutableLineStyle *symbolineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    symbolineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
    CPTPlotSymbol *symbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
    symbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor blackColor]];
    symbol.lineStyle = symbolineStyle;
    symbol.size = CGSizeMake(3.0f, 3.0f);
    self.linePlot.plotSymbol = symbol;

    //set graph grid lines
    CPTMutableLineStyle *gridLineStyle = [[CPTMutableLineStyle alloc] init];
    gridLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor grayColor];
    gridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.5;
    axisSet.xAxis.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle;
    axisSet.yAxis.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle;


    }
```

this is my function for plot init.

Comment: Edit your question with code and output screenshot.

Comment: Please, paste some code :)

Comment: Where?it is print them automaticly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `NSNumberFormatter` and configure it to format the labels however you want. Set the `labelFormatter` on the plot to the new formatter.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"Digit with Three decimal Values = %.3f",999.123456789);
```

This Prints `999.123` // three values after decimal point

Assign text to that label accordingly.

Comment: you should add this while assiging values to the label present on the graph,most probably that will be present inside the Third party library.

Comment: Can you bee more specific accordinf to core-plot libarey?

Answer (score 0):

You are add to:

```
leftAxis.valueFormatter = leftAxis.valueFormatter;

    //remove decimal
    NSNumberFormatter *vf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    vf.generatesDecimalNumbers = NO;
    data.valueFormatter = vf;
```